# Sphinx - How to maintain side bar content between pages?

Tags: markdown, python-sphinx, restructuredtext, read-the-docs, toctree

I have this source directory structure:

```
.
├── conf.py
├── devel
│   └── python
│       ├── Controles de flujo, condicionales y bucles.md
│       ├── Encapsulamiento.md
|       ├── (...)
├── index.rst
├── _static
├── _templates
└── webdevel
```

This is my `index.rst`:

```
¡Bienvenidos a Echemos un bitstazo!
======================================================

Este es mi espacio de documentación personal dónde almaceno todo tipo de conocimientos relacionados con la administración de sistemas y redes informáticas; desarrollo y otros temas varios de IT.

.. toctree::
   :maxdepth: 1 
   :caption: Administración de sistemas

   devel/python/python

Índice y tablas
==================

* :ref:`genindex`
* :ref:`search`
```

This is my `python.rst`:

```
Python
======================================================

.. toctree::
   :maxdepth: 1
   :caption: Contenido:
   :glob:

   *
```

My `conf.py`:

```
project = 'Echemos un bitstazo ~ Wiki'
copyright = '2021, Álvaro Castillo'
author = 'Álvaro Castillo'
extensions = [ 'myst_parser'
]
templates_path = ['_templates']
language = 'es'
exclude_patterns = []
html_theme = 'sphinx_rtd_theme'
html_static_path = ['_static']
```

After do `sphinx-build -b html source build`, I got index.html, python.html...et

I have this index menu:
[image: Index menu]

I have this Python menu:
[image]

However, the menu is changed when I access another page likes Encapsulamiento.
[image]

How I can fix this slide menu bar showing all posts as in python.html?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `Encapsulamiento` to your `toctree` in `index.rst`.

```
.. toctree::
    :maxdepth: 2
    :caption: Administración de sistemas

    devel/python/python
    path/to/encapsulamiento
```

Also change `maxdepth` to `2`.

Comment: Hi!
Thanks for your answer, but It just only adds to the index.html menu item.
https://i.imgur.com/HzLw78M.png

Encapsulamiento--> https://i.imgur.com/Os2SZ02.png

Comment: Perhaps change `maxdepth` to `2`?

Comment: Noup, because If I set maxdepth, I got the index of python.rst inside index.html :/ and It does not solve it.

Comment: Did you do a `make clean` first, then force reload the page? You might be viewing a cached file, either in the browser or in the build directory. Sphinx only rebuilds pages that have changed, and if the only change was in `index.rst` that would be the only page that updated.

Comment: @sincorchetes Would you please accept my answer as the solution by checking it and optionally upvoting it?

Comment: But, your solution was not :maxdepth: 2, was make clean. Can you edit it?

Comment: No. Try `:maxdepth: 1` then `make clean` and `make html`. Clean merely deletes files. You must use the proper `:maxdepth:` setting to get the desired navigation depth.

Comment: If you see my main entry. I used :maxdepth: 1... but I haven't used make clean.

Answer (score 0):

@steve piercy's comment on his answer was what solved this issue for me: `make clean`. As he didn't want to edit his answer I'll post this here so that it doesn't get lost for other people.